# Having trouble with Linked List variable initialization

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I'm having trouble with my Delete(Node p) method, I almost have it completely done but whenever I try to compile it, it says that previous may not have been previously initialized.  Specifically in then if statement in this method below.  I'm brand new to linked lists so I was just trying to practice getting the syntax right.  Any help would be awesome.  Thanks Guys.

```
public Node delete(Node p)
    {
        Node current, previous;
        current = head.next;

        while (current.info != p.info && current.next != null)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if (current.info == p.info)
        {
            previous.next = current.next;
            //this previous here is what is giving me trouble
        }
        return current;
    }
```

//end of trouble method, start of whole code

```
public class LinkedList
    {
        Node head;

        public class Node
        {
            int info;
            Node next;
            Node(int d)
            {
                info = d;
                next = null;
            }
        }

        public void insertAfter(Node prevnode, int new_info)
        {
            if (prevnode == null)
            {
                System.out.println("The given previous node cannot be null");
                return;
            }
            Node newnode = new Node(new_info);
            newnode.next = prevnode.next;
            prevnode.next = newnode;
        }

        public void insertEnd(int new_info)
        {
            Node newnode = new Node(new_info);
            if (head == null)
            {
                head = new Node(new_info);
                return;
            }
            newnode.next = null;
            Node last = head;
            while(last.next != null)
            {
                last = last.next;
            }
            last.next = newnode;
            return;
        }

        public void insertFirst(int new_info)
        {
            Node newnode = new Node(new_info);
            newnode.next = head;
            head = newnode;
        }

        public Node delete(Node p)
        {
            Node current, previous;
            current = head.next;

            while (current.info != p.info && current.next != null)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }

            if (current.info == p.info)
            {
                previous.next = current.next;
            }
            return current;
        }

        public void printList()
        {
            Node tnode = head;
            while (tnode != null)
            {
                System.out.print(tnode.info + " ");
                tnode = tnode.next;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            LinkedList slist = new LinkedList();
            slist.insertEnd(6);
            slist.insertFirst(7);
            slist.insertFirst(1);
            slist.insertEnd(4);
            slist.insertAfter(slist.head.next, 8);

            System.out.println("Top Ten Gaming Scores Are: ");
            slist.printList();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to always initialize `local variables`. Setting  `previous =null` before the while block will resolve your issues.

```
public Node delete(Node p)
    {
        Node current; 
        Node previous =null;
        current = head.next;

        while (current.info != p.info && current.next != null)
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current.next;
        }

        if (current.info == p.info)
        {
            previous.next = current.next;
            //this previous here is what is giving me trouble
        }
        return current;
    }
```

Comment: Awesome that worked, thanks man!  Do you mind explaining why I have to set it like that?  I copied that straight from my notes, which was copied of the blackboard.  My teacher has a reputation of not writing the correct code on the board, so the more I understand, I might be able to copy it down and change what she wrote to better understand.

Comment: In java unlike instance variables (which get initialized by default) You are required to initialize local variables. In your method if the control logic for your while block is not satisfied your local variable `previous` will never get initialized. that is why it is complaining.  to avaoid this you have to explicitly initialize it with a `null` value

Answer (score 0):

If the condition in your while loop: 
`while (current.info != p.info && current.next != null)` never evaluates to true, you do not enter the loop and as the warning says `previous` may not be initialized when you go to use it.

You should make sure to check that `previous != null` before you use it in the if statement.